# How do I create a colormap based on y value with a multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

My question is slightly different from the following

[How to create a colormap based on value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478970/how-to-create-a-colormap-based-on-value)

I can easily complete the above on a single indexed dataframe:

```
func_df=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[col].sort_values().iloc[1::2],df[col].sort_values().iloc[-1::-2]]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)

my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('afmhot_r')

colors = my_cmap(func_df[col])

rects = ax.bar(x=func_df[col].index,
               height=func_df[col], color=colors)
```

in this case colors returns

```
array([[1.        , 0.84901961, 0.34901961, 1.        ],
       [0.58039216, 0.08039216, 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.47843137, 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.22745098, 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.58039216, 0.08039216, 0.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 0.66862745, 0.16862745, 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 0.56862745, 1.        ]])
```

and the code generates
[a bar chart with colors associated with bar height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feIJ7.png)

My new problem is that now I have a dataframe with multiindexed columns. a simple line

```
df.loc[:,(['Covid','Malaria','TB'],['AgOr1'])].plot.bar()
```

allows me to generate the following
[multibar bar chart with three bars one representing each "source"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ut96.png)

however when I try to apply a colormap that correlates with bar height:

```
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('afmhot_r')
colors = my_cmap(df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['AgOr1']]].fillna(0))

df.loc[:,(['Covid','Malaria','TB'],
['AgOr1'])].plot.bar(color=colors)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Invalid color [[0.58039216 0.08039216 0.         1.        ]
 [0.58039216 0.08039216 0.         1.        ]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.        ]]
```

which I suspect is due either to the fact that I am creating a list of colormaps and df.plot.bar(color=colors) does not know how to handle the list of maps or(and more likely) I am doing something incorrect but as a novice python disciple I do not know where to go from here.

Hoping someone has some ideas I can test out.

Cheers!

EDIT: Small bit of dataframe to play around with per mitoRibo request

```
df.head(20).to_dict(orient='list')


Output:
{('Covid', 'AgOr1'): [0.05633802816901407,
  0.061459667093469894,
  0.2676056338028169,
  0.1024327784891165,
  0.048655569782330335,
  0.10627400768245837,
  0.00768245838668373,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan],
 ('Covid', 'AgOr2'): [0.02933673469387755,
  0.012755102040816327,
  1.0,
  0.012755102040816327,
  0.005612244897959183,
  0.030612244897959183,
  0.02933673469387755,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan],
 ('Covid', 'AgOr3'): [0.5092592592592592,
  0.537037037037037,
  0.48148148148148145,
  0.7037037037037037,
  0.7962962962962963,
  0.7685185185185185,
  0.25925925925925924,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan],
 ('Covid', 'AgOr4'): [0.04524699045246991,
  0.20921544209215445,
  0.27148194271481946,
  0.0660024906600249,
  0.13864674138646743,
  0.026567040265670402,
  0.5848899958489,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan],
 ('Covid', 'AgOr5'): [0.04418604651162791,
  0.034883720930232565,
  0.09627906976744185,
  0.043255813953488376,
  0.13953488372093023,
  0.06744186046511629,
  0.02325581395348838,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan],
 ('Malaria', 'AgOr1'): [0.05633802816901407,
  0.061459667093469894,
  0.2676056338028169,
  0.1024327784891165,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.04993597951344429,
  0.09603072983354671,
  nan],
 ('Malaria', 'AgOr2'): [0.02933673469387755,
  0.012755102040816327,
  1.0,
  0.012755102040816327,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.047193877551020405,
  0.10969387755102039,
  nan],
 ('Malaria', 'AgOr3'): [0.5092592592592592,
  0.537037037037037,
  0.48148148148148145,
  0.7037037037037037,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.37037037037037035,
  0.6203703703703703,
  nan],
 ('Malaria', 'AgOr4'): [0.04524699045246991,
  0.20921544209215445,
  0.27148194271481946,
  0.0660024906600249,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.27563304275633044,
  0.2673308426733085,
  nan],
 ('Malaria', 'AgOr5'): [0.04418604651162791,
  0.034883720930232565,
  0.09627906976744185,
  0.043255813953488376,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.034883720930232565,
  0.04883720930232559,
  nan],
 ('TB', 'AgOr1'): [nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.1024327784891165,
  0.048655569782330335,
  nan,
  0.00768245838668373,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.07682458386683737],
 ('TB', 'AgOr2'): [nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.012755102040816327,
  0.005612244897959183,
  nan,
  0.02933673469387755,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.022959183673469385],
 ('TB', 'AgOr3'): [nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.7037037037037037,
  0.7962962962962963,
  nan,
  0.25925925925925924,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.41666666666666663],
 ('TB', 'AgOr4'): [nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.0660024906600249,
  0.13864674138646743,
  nan,
  0.5848899958489,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.2922374429223745],
 ('TB', 'AgOr5'): [nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.043255813953488376,
  0.13953488372093023,
  nan,
  0.02325581395348838,
  nan,
  nan,
  0.018604651162790704]}
```

Comment: Can you share some of your df by editing your question with the output of `df.head(20).to_dict(orient='list')` so I can play around with an example?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! the df has 150 columns so i subsampled the columns as well separately.

Comment: Thanks! However I don't think the following columns are present in the example dataset `['source1','source2','source3'],['receptor'])`. Can you update your barplot making code using the example table you shared?

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to keep things generic. Source1 = Covid Source2=Malaria, Source3=TB, and receptor=AgOr1 i've edited the question to correctly reflect the dataframe

Comment: There's still no `recptor` column which is used in making the `my_cmap`. I tried `df.loc[:,(['Covid','Malaria','TB'],['AgOr1'])].plot.bar(color=['black','red','purple'])` and the plot changed colors as expected

Comment: Crap! Sorry! fixed.. the "recptor" should have been "AgOr1".. I'll get this eventually.

Comment: ok thanks I've now gotten the same error as you! not sure if I'll be able to fix it though

Comment: From what I've seen it's difficult to color each bar separately, is this what you want? The solutions seem to require plotting one bar at a time. Also how is your plot going to color by value AND color by pathogen?